# type inference with rvalue initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

template<typename T> void f(T&& x) {}
template<typename T> void g(std::initializer_list<T> x) {}

int main()
{
    auto   x = {0}; // OK
    auto&& y = {0}; // OK
    g(x); // OK
    g(std::move(x)); // OK
    g({0}); // OK
    f(x); // OK
    f(std::move(x)); // OK
    f({0}); // failure
    return 0;
}
```

rvalue `initializer_list` can be deduced with `auto` but not with `template`.

Why C++ forbids this?

Comment: Probably because `{0}` is treated as a sort of "literal initializer" and intuitively you can't move from a literal (or have an rvalue reference to one you could move from).

Comment: You're missing `#include <utility>`, by the way.

Comment: @chris - you're right. I'll edit

Comment: Why the committee makes this difference is asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582667/why-do-auto-and-template-type-deduction-differ-for-braced-initializers).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is due to 14.8.2.1/1:

> [...] an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5). [*Example:* [...]
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3});                    // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

Now you may think that `auto` is just template argument deduction, but for braced lists `auto` receives special treatment in 7.1.6.4/6:

> replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter U or, if the initializer is a *braced-init-list* (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`. [...] [*Example*:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = { 1, 2 };   // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

Comment: there must be some weird case that makes the committee give the special treatment only to auto

Comment: @a.lasram: I suppose it doesn't hurt to allow `auto x = { 1, 2, 3 };`, so you might as well have it. On the other hand, it *would* probably hurt to allow template argument deduction (I'm thinking constructors).