# Why do auto and template type deduction differ for braced initializers?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction, list-initialization

I understand that, given a braced initializer, `auto` will deduce a type of `std::initializer_list`, while template type deduction will fail:

```
auto var = { 1, 2, 3 };   // type deduced as std::initializer_list<int>

template<class T> void f(T parameter);

f({ 1, 2, 3 });          // doesn't compile; type deduction fails
```

I even know where this is specified in the C++11 standard: 14.8.2.5/5 bullet 5:

> [It's a non-deduced context if the program has] A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter
>   does not have std::initializer_list or reference to possibly cv-qualified std::initializer_list
>   type. [ *Example:*
>
> template void g(T);
>
> g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
>
> —*end example* ]

What I don't know or understand is *why* this difference in type deduction behavior exists. The specification in the C++14 CD is the same as in C++11, so presumably the standardization committee doesn't view the C++11 behavior as a defect.

Does anybody know why `auto` deduces a type for a braced initializer, but templates are not permitted to? While speculative explanations of the form "this could be the reason" are interesting, I'm especially interested in explanations from people who *know* why the standard was written the way it was.

Comment: There was another SO question asked recently on what you figured out. It might have some why in it.

Comment: Ok, found it. The only real why discussion is one comment, but you can take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496268/type-inference-with-rvalue-initializer-list

Comment: Quote from [Scott Meyers](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.cz/2013/07/when-decltype-meets-auto.html): "*I have no idea why type deduction for `auto` and for templates is not identical. If you know, please tell me!*".

Answer (score 15):

There are two important reasons for templates not to do any deduction (the two that I remember in a discussion with the guy in charge)

- Concerns about future language extensions (there are multiple meanings you could invent - what about if we wanted to introduce perfect forwarding for braced init list function arguments?)
- The braces can sometimes validly initialize a function parameter that is dependent

> ```
> template<typename T>
> void assign(T &d, const T& s);
> ```

```
int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  assign(v, { 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

If `T` would be deduced at the right side to `initializer_list<int>` but at the left side to `vector<int>`, this would fail to work because of a contradictional argument deduction.

The deduction for `auto` to `initializer_list<T>` is controversial. There exist a proposal for C++-after-14 to remove it (and to ban initialization with `{ }` or `{a, b}`, and to make `{a}` deduce to the type of `a`).

Answer (score 3):

The reason is described in [N2640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf):

> A {}-list cannot deduce against a plain type parameter `T`. For example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void count(T); // (1).
> struct Dimensions { Dimensions(int, int); };
> size_t count(Dimensions); // (2).
> size_t n = count({1, 2}); // Calls (2); deduction doesn't
>                           // succeed for (1).
> ```
>
> Another example:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> void inc(T, int); // (1)
> template<class T>
> void inc(std::initializer_list<T>, long); // (2)
> inc({1, 2, 3}, 3); // Calls (2). (If deduction had succeeded
>                    // for (1), (1) would have been called — a
>                    // surprise.)
> ```
>
> On the other hand, being able to deduce an `initializer_list<X>` for `T` is attractive to
>   allow:
>
> ```
> auto x = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 };
> f(x);
> g(x);
> ```
>
> which was deemed desirable behavior since the very beginning of the EWG discussions about
>   initializer lists.
>
> Rather than coming up with a clever deduction rule for a parameter type `T` matched with a {}-list (an option we pursued in earlier sketches and drafts of this paper), we now prefer to handle this with a special case for "auto" variable deduction when the initializer is a {}-list. I.e., for the specific case of a variable declared with an "auto" type specifier and a {}-list initializer, the "auto" is deduced as for a function `f(initializer_list<T>)` instead of as for a function `f(T)`.

For conclusion, the problem is that if we allow a {}-list to deduce against a plain type parameter `T`, then the function with parameter `T` would have very high priority during overload resolution, which may cause wired behavior (like the examples above).

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's "speculative explanations of the form "this could be the reason"" as you call it.

`{1,2,3}` is not only `std::initializer_list<int>` but also allow initialize types without constructor. For example:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct x{
    int a,b,c;
};

void f(x){

}
int main() {
    f({1,2,3});
}
```

is correct code. To show that it isn't `initializer_list` let's see the following code:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct x{int a,b,c;};

void f(x){

}
int main() {
    auto il = {1, 2, 3};
    f(il);
}
```

Error is:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:10:9: error: could not convert ‘il’ from ‘std::initializer_list<int>’ to ‘x’
```

And now to the question "What is the difference?"

in `auto x = {1, 2, 3};` code it's OK to determine type, because coder explicitly said "It's not important what's type it is" using `auto`

While in case of function template he may be sure that he is using different type. And it's good to prevent errors in ambiguous cases (It doesn't seem like C++ style , through).

Especially bad it will be in case when there was 1 function `f(x)` and then it was changed to template one. Programmer wrote to use it as `x`, and after adding new function for other type it slightly change to call completely different one.

Comment: I don't understand how saying `auto` means "it's not important what the type is," but saying `template<typename T>` means something different. In both cases, you run the risk that the type deduced may not be what the programmer intended.

Comment: I dont understand the second code. You write "To show that it isnt initializer list" but in the example `{1,2,3}` is a initializer list, hence the error...

Comment: I mean I'm showing that in first code it's not initializer_list. Because when it's initialzer_list it doesn't work