# Why does auto x{3} deduce an initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, initializer-list, type-deduction

I love `auto` in C++11. It's wonderful. But it has one inconsistency that really gets on my nerves, because I trip over it all the time:

```
int i = 3;       // i is an int with value 3
int i = int{3};  // i is an int with value 3
int i(3);        // i is an int with value 3 (possibly narrowing, not in this case)
int i{3};        // i is an int with value 3

auto i = 3;      // i is an int with value 3
auto i = int{3}; // i is an int with value 3
auto i(3);       // i is an int with value 3
auto i{3};       // wtf, i is a std::initializer_list<int>?!
```

This strange behaviour is confusing for newcomers, and annoying for experienced users -- C++ has enough little inconsistencies and corner cases that one has to keep in mind as it is. Can anybody explain why standards committee decided to introduce a new one in this case?

I could understand it if declaring a variable of type `std::initializer_list` was something that was useful or done frequently, but in my experience it's almost never deliberate -- and in the rare cases where you did want to do it, any of

```
std::initializer_list<int> l{3};
auto l = std::initializer_list<int>{3};
auto l = {3}; // No need to specify the type
```

would work just fine. So what's the reason behind the special case for `auto x{i}`?

Comment: That's pretty much why the [rule is going to change](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17582667

Comment: Solution: don't use auto for any of those cases (except #2). :-)

Comment: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html

Comment: if you're asking "why C++ committee have done a wrong design choice, which they are now trying to undo", well, frankly, the answer is "*because they are human beings and as such they sometimes may do things that are wrong or controversial*"?" I honestly guess that the only real way to get a definite answer would be to ask one of the members of the committee directly.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To make long story short:

- a braced initializer expression `{}` has no type by itself
- `auto` has to infer type information
- `int{3}` obviously means "create an `int` var with value taken from initializer list", thus its type is just `int` and can be used in any wider context (`int i = int{3}` will work and `auto i = int{3}` can deduce type, because right side is obviously of type `int`)
- `{3}` by itself has no type (it **can't** be `int`, because it's not a *value* but an *initializer list*), so `auto` wouldn't work — but, because committee considered that `auto` should still work in this case, they decided that the "best" type for (yeah, typeless by definition) initializer list would be... `std::initializer_list`, as you already probably guessed.

But, as you pointed out, this made the whole behaviour of `auto` quite semantically inconsistent. That's why there were proposals to change it — namely **N3681**, **N3912** and **N3922** — submitted to the committee. Former proposal was REJECTED as FI3 due to no committee consensus on this matter, http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3852.html#FI3 , current (**N3922**) got [**adopted** ca. Q1 of 2015](http://herbsutter.com/2014/11/24/updates-to-my-trip-report/);

*tl;dr* you may assume that [standards-compliant compilers<sup>1</sup>](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-12/msg01129.html) with [bleeding-edge C++ support<sup>2</sup>](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#n3922) either have the new, more sane-ish semantics already in place, or will have it shortly.

> The Standardization Committee acknowledged the problem by adopting N3922 into draft C++17.

— so it's

```
auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
auto x3{ 1, 2 }; // error: not a single element
auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x5{ 3 }; // decltype(x5) is int
```

now, for better or worse.

<sub>further reading:</sub>

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3912.html

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html

http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html

http://herbsutter.com/2014/11/24/updates-to-my-trip-report/

---

<sup>1</sup>GCC 5.1 (& up) [apparently uses N3922 even in C++11/C++14 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007692/why-does-g5-deduces-object-instead-of-initializer-list-in-auto-type-deduction)

<sup>2</sup>Clang 3.8, with the caveat

> This is a backwards-incompatible change that is applied to all language versions that allow type deduction from auto (per the request of the C++ committee).

Comment: N3922 was adopted more than a year ago (November 2014, in Urbana).

Comment: @T.C. many thanks for spotting that one - and strange that no one mentioned it earlier!

Comment: @vaxquis Do you guys know when this will be accepted and applied to most compilers like g++ and clang?

Comment: @Curious browsing the official compiler docs or using google should answer this question for you better than I can. Still, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @vaxquis Why does X3 (direct initialized) is an error and X1 (copy initialized) is acceptable?

Comment: @gedamial see the linked articles for explanation. note that `x1` is acceptable because RH is visibly `std::initializer_list<int>` - OTOH, direct initialization of a primitive requires a single `{value}` parameter, so with `{value1,value2}` it makes little sense.

Comment: Confusingly, current GCC and Clang reject `auto i{1,2};` even in C++11 mode, though it is valid in this standard version, and is accepted by e.g. GCC 4.8 (deduced to `std::initializer_list<int>`). I have read N3922 which says this deduction is considered a defect in C++14. So this means, retroactively, even programs written against older standard versions are considered ill-formed?

Comment: @ArneVogel I would suppose so. The answer quoted Clang’s explicit caveat that the change was backward-incompatible and applied to *all language versions*.