# Properly initialising variables in modern C++ (C++11 and above), using () or {}?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

The [C++ reference pages](http://cppreference.com) say that () is for value initialisation, {} is for value and aggregate and list initialisation. So, if I just want value initialisation, which one do I use? () or {}? I'm asking because in the book "A Tour of C++" by Bjarne himself, he seems to prefer using {}, even for value initialisation (see for example pages 6 and 7), and so I thought it was good practice to always use {}, even for value initialisation. *However*, I've been badly bitten by the following bug recently. Consider the following code.

```
auto p = std::make_shared<int>(3);
auto q{ p };
auto r(p);
```

Now according to the compiler (Visual Studio 2013), `q` has type `std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<int>>`, which is not what I intended. What I actually intended for `q` is actually what `r` is, which is `std::shared_ptr<int>`. So in this case, I should *not* use {} for value initialisation, but use (). Given this, why does Bjarne in his book still seem to prefer to use {} for value initialisation? For example, he uses `double d2{2.3}` at the bottom of page 6.

To definitively answer my questions, when should I use () and when should I use {}? And is it a matter of syntax correctness or a matter of good programming practice?

Oh and uh, plain English if possible please.

EDIT:
It seems that I've slightly misunderstood *value initialisation* (see answers below). However the questions above still stands by and large.

Comment: I think this question is more about an interaction between `auto` and `{...}` than about the differences between `{...}` and `(...)`.

Comment: welcome to the joy of working in a language that was made up as we went along

Comment: A rule of thumb I have heard is use {} until it doesn't work then use ().  Also things are slated to change: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25612534/4342498

Comment: To further prove @pm100's point, in C++17, `auto q{p};` will do what you expected it to (at least per the Rapperswil meeting). I'd say learn where not to use {} and avoid braces in those cases, but as that doesn't happen all too often, {} works *almost* everywhere. There's been discussion of using {{}} vs. {} to differentiate between list constructors and other constructors. Unfortunately, making {{}} use the list constructor would not be the backward-compatible choice.

Comment: See also [Scott Meyers on `auto` and `{}`](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/02/why-auto-deduces-stdinitializerlist-for.html). Personally, I think the behavior of `{}` will still be badly broken even in C++17, because even without `auto` you can still get an unexpected choice of constructor calls using `{}`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is my opinion.

When using `auto` as type specifier, it's cleaner to use:

```
auto q = p;   // Type of q is same as type of p
auto r = {p}; // Type of r is std::initializer_list<...>
```

When using explicit type specifier, it's better to use `{}` instead of `()`.

```
int a{};   // Value initialized to 0
int b();   // Declares a function (the most vexing parse)
```

One could use

```
int a = 0; // Value initialized to 0
```

However, the form

```
int a{};
```

can be used to value initialize objects of user defined types too. E.g.

```
struct Foo
{
   int a;
   double b;
};


Foo f1 = 0;  // Not allowed.
Foo f1{};    // Zero initialized.
```

Comment: In the latter case `int a = 0;`  is definitely superior in conciseness and readability.

Comment: @Columbo, the form `int a{};` can be used to zero initialize user defined types too.

Comment: Yeah, but in that case `T a = {};` is a bit nicer, IMHO. For scalars, copy-initialization is definitely the way to go though.

Comment: @Columbo, We might eventually come up with objective reasons why one method is superior to the other. In the mean time, it seems to be a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 30):

Scott Meyers has a fair amount to say about the difference between the two methods of initialization in his book [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do).

He summarizes both approaches like this:

> Most developers end up choosing one kind of delimiter as a default, using
>   the other only when they have to. Braces-by-default folks are
>   attracted by their unrivaled breadth of applicability, their
>   prohibition of narrowing conversions, and their immunity to C++’s most
>   vexing parse. Such folks understand that in some cases (e.g., creation
>   of a `std::vector` with a given size and initial element value),
>   parentheses are required. On the other hand, the go-parentheses-go
>   crowd embraces parentheses as their default argument delimiter.
>   They’re attracted to its consistency with the C++98 syntactic
>   tradition, its avoidance of the auto-deduced-a-std::initializer_list
>   problem, and the knowledge that their object creation calls won’t be
>   inadvertently waylaid by `std::initializer_list` constructors. They
>   concede that sometimes only braces will do (e.g., when creating a
>   container with particular values). There’s no consensus that either
>   approach is better than the other, so my advice is to pick one and
>   apply it consistently.

Comment: 80% of my upvote to Scott Meyer, 20% to you for referring to his quote.

Answer (score 7):

First off, there seems to a terminology mixup. What you have is *not* value initialisation. Value initialisation happens when you do not provide any explicit initialisation arguments. `int x;` uses default initialisation, the value of `x` will be unspecified. `int x{};` uses value initialisation, `x` will be `0`. `int x();` declares a function—that's why `{}` is preferred for value initialisation.

The code you've shown does not use value initialisation. With `auto`, the safest thing is to use copy initialisation:

```
auto q = p;
```

Comment: Ah I see my confusion of terms. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

There is another important difference: The brace initializer requires that the given type can actually hold the given value. In other words, it forbids narrowing of the value, like rounding or truncation.

```
int a(2.3); // ok? a will hold the value 2, no error, maybe compiler warning
uint8_t c(256); // ok? the compiler should warn about something fishy going on
```

As compared to the brace initialization

```
int A{2.3}; // compiler error, because int can NOT hold a floating point value
double B{2.3}; // ok, double can hold this value
uint8_t C{256}; // compiler error, because 8bit is not wide enough for this number
```

Especially in generic programming with templates you should therefore use brace initialization to avoid nasty surprises when the underlying type does something unexpected to your input values.

Answer (score 2):

{} is value initialization if empty, if not it is list/aggregate initialization.

From the draft, **7.1.6.4 auto specifier,  7/... Example**,

`auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>`

Rules are a little bit complex to explain here (even hard to read from the source!).

Comment: How does your standard... "reference"... explain your first sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Herb Sutter seems to be making an [argument in CppCon 2014 (39:25 into the talk)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64) for using auto and brace initializers, like so:

```
auto x = MyType { initializers };
```

whenever you want to coerce the type, for left-to-right consistency in definitions:

- Type-deduced: `auto x = getSomething()`
- Type-coerced: `auto x = MyType { blah }`
- User-defined literals `auto x = "Hello, world."s`
- Function declaration: `auto f { some; commands; } -> MyType`
- Named Lambda: `using auto f = [=]( { some; commands; } -> MyType`
- C++11-style typedef: `using AnotherType = SomeTemplate<MyTemplateArg>`

Answer (score 0):

Scott Mayers just posted a relevant blog entry [Thoughts on the Vagaries of C++ Initialization](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/09/thoughts-on-vagaries-of-c-initialization.html). It seems that C++ still has a way to go before achieving a truly uniform initialization syntax.