# Direct list initialization compiles successfully, but normal direct initialization fails, why?

Tags: c++, initialization, overload-resolution

For example, code like this:

```
struct A { A(int); };
struct B { B(A);   };

int main()
{
    B b{{0}}; // OK
    B c({0}); // error
}
```

The error messages are:

```
f.cc: In function 'int main()':
f.cc:7:9: error: call of overloaded 'B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
  B c({0}); // error

         ^
f.cc:7:9: note: candidates are:
f.cc:2:12: note: B::B(A)
 struct B { B(A);   };
        ^
f.cc:2:8: note: constexpr B::B(const B&)
 struct B { B(A);   };
        ^
f.cc:2:8: note: constexpr B::B(B&&)
```

Comment: Yes, it should be public. I have changed that, thanks!

Comment: Surprisingly, this fails, even when I delete copy and move constructors of B: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fb30cd9d5839ac2 Compilation error message is rather baffling, it is ambiguous with deleted functions.

Comment: @ChrisBeck deleted functions participate in overload resolution, so it is not baffling that deleting them makes no difference

Comment: B b({{{0}}});

This compiles, I have no idea why. Voodoo perhaps?

Comment: I think the brace form of constructing `{}` never assumes an *initializer list* but the paren  version `()` always does, even when there is no *initializer list* constructor. This answer gives some info, but not a definitive answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851502/properly-initialising-variables-in-modern-c-c11-and-above-using-or/29851993#29851993

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of the latest official standard, C++14, your first initialization is not ambiguous. [over.match.list]:

[image]

As no initializer-list constructors exist, we enter the "second phase". And now consider [over.best.ics]/4:

[image]

Our element is `{0}`. Hence **this disallows the (user-defined) conversion `{0}` -> `A` for the copy constructor**. Clearly, this doesn't apply if we aren't in the second phase of [over.match.list], so for your example with `B c({0})`, no list-initialization occurs for `c` and both constructors are considered.

---

### CWG issue 1467

The first initialization is currently just as ambiguous as the second one. Compilers simply haven't implemented CWG [**#1467**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) yet - its resolution removed bullet point (4.5), quoted above.
See [**#2076**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2076), which opts to revert the change:

> The resolution of [issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) made some plausible constructs
>   ill-formed. For example,
>
> ```
> struct A { A(int); };
> struct B { B(A); };
> B b{{0}};
> ```
>
> This is now ambiguous, because the text disallowing user-defined
>   conversions for `B`'s copy and move constructors was removed from
>   13.3.3.1 [over.best.ics] paragraph 4.

"The text" is the aforementioned bullet point. Richard Smith proposes the following wording:

> For non-class types, we allow initialization from a single-item list
>   to perform a copy only if the element within the list is not itself a
>   list (13.3.3.1.5 [over.ics.list] bullet 9.1). **The analogous rule for
>   this case would be to add back the bullet in 13.3.3.1 [over.best.ics]
>   paragraph 4, but only in the case where the initializer is itself an
>   initializer list**:
>
> the second phase of
>   13.3.1.7 [over.match.list] when the initializer list has exactly one            element that is
>   itself an initializer list, where the target is the first parameter of
>   a constructor
>           of class `X`, and the conversion is
>   to `X` or reference to (possibly cv-qualified) `X`,

As the initializer `{0}` is itself an initializer list, that bullet point would make your first initialization well-formed again.