# Overload resolution gets different result between gcc and clang

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

```
struct A { A(int);};
struct B { explicit B(A); B(const B&);};
B b({0});
```

gcc 5.1.0 gives the error

```
/dev/fd/63:3:8: error: call of overloaded 'B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
 is ambiguous
/dev/fd/63:3:8: note: candidates are:
/dev/fd/63:2:27: note: B::B(const B&)
/dev/fd/63:2:21: note: B::B(A)
```

while clang 3.6.0 succeeds.

Which one is right? Why?

For gcc 5.1.0: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pVe9eyXgu26NEX6X

For clang 3.6.0: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WOi1md2dc519SPW0

This may be similar to [Direct list initialization compiles successfully, but normal direct initialization fails, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469979/direct-list-initialization-compiles-successfully-but-normal-direct-initializati) which gcc and clang get same result.

But this is a different question. `B(A)` is explicit here. gcc and clang get different results.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32469979/3647361?

Comment: @Columbo `B(A)` is explicit here and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469979/direct-list-initialization-compiles-successfully-but-normal-direct-initializati both gcc and clang get same result but here is different.

Comment: My guess is it's due to different default standards/standard support.

Comment: @Columbo the added twist here is the `explicit`, which even though `{0} -> const B&` is copy-list initialization *does* consider explicit constructors during overload resolution, just making the program ill-formed if one is selected. That's probably enough of a difference to keep this question as a non-dupe.

Comment: The reason that clang accepts this appears to be that it doesn't consider explicit constructors when doing overload resolution for 13.3.1.7 rather than considering them and erroring out later . See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6837d255e03c8775 . This is understandable, given the confusion that RichardSmith reported to the committee in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference can be reduced to

```
struct A { explicit A(int); };
struct B { B(int); };
void f(A);
void f(B);

int main() {
    f({ 1 });
}
```

On GCC this fails, in accordance to the Standard (which says that for list initialization, explicit constructors are considered - so they can yield an ambiguity - but they just are not allowed to be selected). Clang accepts it and calls the second function.

In your case, what @Columbo says in his answer to [Direct list initialization compiles successfully, but normal direct initialization fails, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32469979/3647361) applies. With the difference that in your case, `B(const B&);` is not anymore acceptable to Clang because the `{0} -> B` conversion would be faced with two possibilities: the explicit constructor or using the copy constructor recursively a second time. The first option, as explained above, will not be considered by clang and this time the explanation by @Columbo applies and the copy constructor cannot be used a second time because that would need a user defined conversion as we have a single element (here, `0`). So in the summary, only the first constructor succeeds and is taken.

---

Since I understand the issue is about weird overload resolution rules and some might not be able to follow, here's a more intuitive explanation. The rules that are active are, in order

- `b({0})` means goto http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17 and from there to http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ctor which is our first OR context . The two constructors enumerated are  `B(A);` and `B(const B&)` with argument `{0}`.

  - For `B(A)` it works with a single user defined conversion.
  - For `B(const B&)`, we need to initialize a `const B&` which brings us to http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#8 then to http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#2 (by help of http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#dcl.init.list-3 "Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is copy-list-initialized ...") then to http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#over.ics.list-6. The resulting OR context has candidates `B(A);` and `B(const B&)`, with the argument `0`. This is our second OR context and is copy-list-initialization by 13.3.1.7 (as required by over.ics.ref#2 and dcl.init.list-3).

    - For `B(A)`, the constructor is explicit and therefore ignored by Clang (in contradiction with the spec) but accepted by GCC (hence the ambiguity).
    - For `B(const B&)`, this is the scenario handled by @Columbo and therefore the user-defined conversion which would be needed is forbidden. Newer drafts don't have this rule anymore (but probably it will be added back). But because the `0` to `const B&` would be a normal user-defined conversion (not a list initialization), it would ignore the explicit constructor needed for the conversion anyway (for this potential second use of the copy constructor), and therefore the user-defined conversion wouldn't be possible anyway and the rule is of much less significance than I thought when I wrote the above shorter summary.

Therefore for GCC it can use the explicit constructor directly, and in addition by a single use of the copy constructor. For clang, it only considers using the explicit constructor directly, and it won't use it indirectly by a copy-list-initialization using the copy constructor like GCC does. Both won't consider using the copy constructor a second time, and it's irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

The correct list initialization semantics is

```
B b{0};
```

which compiles fine. If you write `B b({0});`, the gcc can't decide if call `B(A)` directly or create `B` (`{0}`) and then copy it with `B(const B&)` in the second phase. There is no priority ordering between these two options.

It's language problem, not compiler's problem. See this [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52522).