# Why does g++5 deduces object instead of initializer_list in auto type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, clang++, gcc5

I recently came upon this code:

```
struct Foo{};

int main() 
{
    Foo a;
    // clang++ deduces std::initializer_list
    // g++5.1 deduces Foo
    auto b{a}; 
    a = b;
}
```

It compiles fine with g++5.1, but fails in clang++ (used both `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`, same results). The reason is that [clang++ deduces the type of `b` as `std::initializer_list<Foo>`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gjt1owTIlDBF9tLn), whereas [`g++5.1` deduces as `Foo`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nTpRyUzIsjBKCuFj). **AFAIK, the type should indeed be (counter-intuitive indeed) `std::initializer_list` here**. Why does g++5 deduces the type as `Foo`?

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried both `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`

Comment: In that case, it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Anyway, you should put that kind of information in the question. It kind of invlidates the answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Added, although I marked the question with `c++11`

Comment: @juanchopanza: Is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If `-std-c++11` or `-std=c++14` are used, then I'd say yes.

Comment: See [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html). In particular, "Direction from EWG is that we consider this a defect in C++14."

Comment: @vaxquis That's not a dupe. As I mentioned in the question, I knew that the type should be `initializer_list`. The rules changed a bit as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a proposal for C++1z that implements new type deduction rules for brace initialization ([N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html)), and I guess gcc implemented them:

> For direct list-initialization:
>   1. For a braced-init-list with only a single element, auto deduction will deduce from that entry;
>   2. For a braced-init-list with more than one element, auto deduction will be ill-formed.
>
> *[Example:*
>
> ```
> auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
> auto x3{ 1, 2 }; // error: not a single element
> auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x5{ 3 }; // decltype(x5) is int.
> ```
>
> *-- end example]*

Here is the [gcc patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-12/msg01129.html) concerning the new changes with regards to "Unicorn initialization."

Comment: LOL @ "unicorn initialization". So much better than "uniform".