# why this variable isn't deduced as initializer_list in g++ in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, c++17, list-initialization

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int fact = 1;
    for(auto i{1};i<=n;i++)
        fact*=i;
    std::cout<<"fact of "<<n<<" is "<<fact;
}
```

It compiles fine on ideone even when I use `-std=c++14` option. See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/zQmmtq).  But in C++14 the variable `i` should be deduced as `initializer_list` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007692/why-does-g5-deduces-object-instead-of-initializer-list-in-auto-type-deduction).

There is a proposal for C++1z that implements new type deduction rules for brace initialization:

> For direct list-initialization:
>
> 1. For a braced-init-list with only a single element, auto deduction will deduce from that entry;
> 2. For a braced-init-list with more than one element, auto deduction will be ill-formed.
>
> [Example:
>
> auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list
>
> auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
>
> auto x3{ 1, 2 }; // error: not a single element
>
> auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list
>
> auto x5{ 3 }; // decltype(x5) is int.
>
> -- end example]

So, the rules changed in C++17.  As such, the program shouldn't compile when I use `-std=c++14`. Is this bug in g++?  Shouldn't the variable `i` deduced as `initializer_list` in C++14?

Comment: See [Different compiler behavior for expression: auto p {make_pointer()};](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31301369/1708801), it is unclear if the proposal mentioned in there should be applied to C++14 or not, there is conflicting information wrt to this. There is implementation divergence here as well.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It looks like [the Clang devs intend to (eventually) apply this change retroactively too](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20150209/123102.html).

Comment: @T.C. thank you for digging that up, interesting but head is currently `3.8` and the behavior has not changed and it still doesn't answer whether this was decided as a defect or not :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is a proposal for C++1z that implements new type deduction rules for brace initialization

Not exactly. If you follow the link to the actual paper, it reads:

> Direction from EWG is that we consider this a defect in C++14.

Which is enough to get implementors to also treat it as a defect, and hence change the compiler behaviour even in C++14 mode.

Comment: You can make an argument that an implementation shouldn't treat it as a C++14 defect until there's an official DR, but I wouldn't be convinced by such an argument, I think the GCC behaviour is at least not wrong.

Comment: If you don't nip these things in the bud, the trailing edge of conformance can get a little out of hand. I'm reminded of the nightmare that is web browser compliance: `Microsoft said that Acid3 did not agree with the goal of [IE8] and that IE8 would improve only some of the standards... scored 20/100, which is much worse than all relevant competitors...` IMHO, GCC can step *exclusively* on toes if that's what it takes to keep that kind of divergence in check.