# How get gcc and MSVC to apply the current C++ rules for auto type deduction with list-initializers?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, gcc, auto

In C++11 and C++14, this code

```
auto x { 10 };
```

should cause x's type to be deduced as `std::initializer_list<int>`. That's been changed in draft C++17 (there, x's type is deduced to be `int`), but according to the current Standard, x's type should be `std::initializer_list<int>`.

I can't find a way to get g++ 5.1.0 to deduce the correct type. Even with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`, x's type is deduced to be `int`.

I have the same problem with the current MSVC compiler Even with `/Za`, x's type is deduced to be `int`.

Here's the test program I'm using. It should compile without error.  (Clang issues a warning, but I'm not concerned about that.)

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  auto x1 {0};
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x1), std::initializer_list<int>>::value == 1,
                "x1 has unexpected type");
}
```

Comment: Related to(maybe duplicate) [Different compiler behavior for expression: auto p {make_pointer()};](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31301369/1708801) ... there is ambiguity over whether this is a C++14 defect or a C++1z proposal which may explain implementation differences.

Comment: I don't see how this matter can be viewed as related to a defect. The [linked-to SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31301369/1708801) refers to [EWG 161](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4422.html#161), a topic being dealt with by the language evolution working group--the group evolving the language for future standards. [N4458](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4458.html) seems to be the most recent document summarizing core language defects, and I don't see any mention there of N3922.

Comment: There's no way to get the old, awful behavior with Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe see the actual [EWG issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4422.html#161) ... `N3922` was the last version and was the version adopted at Urbana. The proposal itself recommend even though it is coming out of EWG to be considered a defect which is different but I think is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis any insight into whether this ended up being considered a defect or not? In [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31301568/1708801) there is conflicting evidence.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I don't know. I would consider the entire original C++11 specification of initializer lists/brace initialization/uniform initialization to be fundamentally defective in its entirety. But I don't attend committee meetings and can't say whether this is "officially" a defect.