# C++11: when does compiler consider {} as std::initializer_list, and when doesn't?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, initializer-list

I've got a quick sample:

```
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    int i;
    char c;
};

void f(const A&){}

template<class T>
void g(T&& t)
{
    f(forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    A a={1,'@'};//OK
    f({1,'#'});//OK
    g({1,'@'});//Compilation error
    return 0;
}
```

Clang will give this error:

```
    testArray.cpp:16:5: error: no matching function for call to 'g'
        g({1,'@'});//fix: g<A>({1,'@'})
        ^
    testArray.cpp:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer
          template argument 'T'
    void g(T&& t)
         ^
```

My questions are:

1. In `A a={1,'@'};`, if `{}` is deduced as `std::initializer_list`, then how is it converted from `std::initilizer_list` to type `A`?
2. In `f({1,'#'});`, when `f` requires a type `A`, does the compiler implicitly generate an `A` object, or does it convert from `std::initializer_list` to `A`?
3. why, when `g()` is a template, does the template type deduction not work to give a type `A`? Does `std::forward` help to convey the message from `f` to `g`, say that `T` is type `A`?

Comment: This has changed somewhat in C++17, so when you say "C++11" do you really mean C++11, or do you mean "modern C++" in general?

Comment: For situation 3, this might work: `g(A{t,'@'});` since proper type deduction should happen through the temporary.

Comment: @JerryCoffin note that [the C++17 changes were considered due to a defect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31301369/1708801) and so in the recent compilers they apply them back to C+11 and C++14. Although there was inconsistency for a while in this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. In 'A a={1,'@'}'' :If {} is deduced as std::initializer_list, then how it's converted from std::initilizer_list to type A?

No, it has nothing to do with `std::initializer_list`. `a` is just [copy-list-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) from `{1,'@'}`.

> 2. In 'f({1,'#'});' When f requires a type A, does compiler implicitly generates an A object, or it converts from std::initializer_list to A?

It still has nothing to do with `std::initializer_list`. The function parameter is [copy-list-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) from `{1,'#'}`.

> 3. why when "g()" is a template, the template type deduction doesn't work to give a type A? Does "forward" help to convey the message from f to g, say that T is type A()?

Because this belongs to [non deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), the template parameter `T` can't be deduced and cause the compile error.

> 6) The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not std::initializer_list or a reference to one:

And

> when does compiler consider {} as std::initializer_list, and when doesn't?

When you declare the funciton parameter type as `std::initializer_list` and you pass a braced list as argument, then `std::initializer_list` will be constructed. Another case is for `auto`, e.g.

```
auto x1 = {3}; // x1 is deduced as std::initializer_list<int>
auto x2{1, 2}; // after C++17, error: not a single element
               // before C++17, it was std::initializer_list<int>
auto x3{3};    // after C++17, x3 is deduces as int
               // before C++17 it was std::initializer_list<int>
```

---

BTW: Even with `auto` it won't work for `{1,'@'}`, should it be `std::initializer_list<char>`, or `std::initializer_list<int>`?