# auto and brace initialization in C++11/C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, c++14

When I compile the below code with clang and gcc `T` is deduced differently.

```
#include<initializer_list> //for clang

//to see how T is deduced(form compiler error).
template<typename T>
void foo(T);

int main() {
    auto var1{2};
    foo(var1);
}
```

Here is what I got.

```
clang 3.6(c++11/c++14)
gcc 4.9(c++11/c++14) 
T = std::initializer_list<int>

gcc 5.1(c++11/c++14)
T = int
```

I think `T` should be `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Why is `T = int` in gcc 5.1?

Comment: If my memory serves me well, there was a change (maybe even a late change) in the spec between C++11 and C++14 in this area - I'll try find a link for it.

Comment: Noteworthy is that C++14 support in clang3.6 is definitely "not complete", and I expect that the same applies for gcc 4.9 - possibly also 5.0. So if it's "something late in the spec" or just "something nobody had implemented yet", it may well be changing in new releases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is proposed change to the C++17 specification - [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) (I'm not sure if it has been accepted yet).

Basically this [presentation from Scott Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf), slide 20 covers the new rules.

```
auto var1 {2} ;
```

Here, `var1` will be deduced to be an `int`.

It does look like some compilers have already implemented the change. I believe the change is more "intuitive" but your mileage may vary. I think in this interim phase, prefer the `=` initialisation, it may be more portable.

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612534/3747990) has some more detail on the history of the proposals and defects raised.

Comment: And clang as of last week (july 2nd) still treats it as `initializer_list` - with a warning that "initalization of a variable with deduced type should use = for assignment".

Comment: Clang warns that "meaning of `auto{expr}` will change in a future version", presumably to the behaviour we all expected all along"