# std::map of tuple to tuple and using emplace

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code, compiled with g++ 7.0.1 (-std=c++17):

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    // Create an alias for a tuple of three ints
    using ThreeTuple=std::tuple<int,int,int>;
    // Create an alias for a map of tuple to tuple (of three ints)
    using MapThreeTupleToThreeTuple=std::map<ThreeTuple,ThreeTuple>;

    MapThreeTupleToThreeTuple m;

    // The following does NOT compile
    m.emplace({1,2,3},{4,5,6});

    // ..., and neither does this
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,{1,2,3},{4,5,6});
}
```

I would have thought that the `initializer_list` arguments to `map::emplace()` would have sufficed and would have resulted in the insertion of the tuple key to tuple value association as specified. Apparently, the compiler disagrees.

Of course creating a tuple explicitly (i.e., `ThreeTuple{1,2,3}` instead of just `{1,2,3}`) and passing that to `map::emplace()` solves the problem, but why can't the initializer lists be passed directly to `map::emplace()` which would automatically forward them to the tuple constructors?

Comment: initializer lists have no type.  `emplace` relies on type deduction.  You can't deduce a type for a typeless thing.

Comment: What do you think has changed in C++17 regarding this issue?

Comment: @Walter, I didn't mean to imply that I am using a new C++17 feature, just that I was using C++17 compatibility level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but why can't the initializer lists be passed directly to `map::emplace()`

Because initializer lists aren't expressions and so they don't have types. The signature for [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) is just:

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

and you can't deduce a type from `{1,2,3}`. You couldn't in C++11 and you still can't in C++1z. The only exception to this rule is if the template parameter is of the form `std::initializer_list<T>` where `T` is a template parameter.

In order for `m.emplace({1,2,3},{4,5,6});` to work, you'd need a signature like:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace(key_type&&, mapped_type&&);
```

Comment: What about the version with `std::piecewise_construct`? Same problem?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Yeah. It's still just the one `emplace()` function template.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Do note that there are `initializer_list` and there are *initializer list*.  A `initializer_list` can be constructed from a *initializer list* as it knows what the type should be.  A plain template type does not so it fails.

Comment: @NathanOliver, interesting, I thought that my `{1,2,3}` argument (would have automatically) resulted in an `std::initializer_list<int>` parameter being deduced.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn That is only when using `auto` as it is *special*.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612262/why-does-auto-x3-deduce-an-initializer-list

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, no changes in C++17 matter in this context. As explained by NathanOliver and Barry, `{1,2,3}` cannot be deduced to have any type and hence cannot be matched against a template argument. You must provide the arguments for the constructor of `ThreeTuple` as deducible types, i.e.

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(1,2,3),
          std::forward_as_tuple(4,5,6));
```

which calls the constructor

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
template<typename... Args1, typename... Args2 >
std::pair<T1,T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t,
                       std::tuple<Args1...>, std::tuple<Args2...>);
```

In this particular case, you can even omit the `std::piecewise_construct`

```
m.emplace(std::forward_as_tuple(1,2,3),
          std::forward_as_tuple(4,5,6));
```

or (in C++17 as pointed out by Nicol in a comment)

```
m.emplace(std::tuple(1,2,3), std::tuple(4,5,6));
```

which are equivalent to

```
m.emplace(ThreeTuple(1,2,3), ThreeTuple(4,5,6));
```

and call the constructor

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::pair<T1,T2>::pair(const&T1, const&T2);
```

---

Note also that AFAIK you cannot get this working by using `std::initializer_list<int>` explicitly. The reason is simply that there is not suitable constructor for `pair<ThreeTuple,ThreeTuple>` (the `value_type` of your map).

Comment: Have a +1 for showing a working example of how to do this properly.

Comment: FYI: since the OP is using C++17, you could also use template class deduction and therefore just use `std::tuple(1, 2, 3)`. Assuming the compiler supports it and the standard library properly implements it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Correct, but that is almost the same as `ThreeTuple(1,2,3)`, which the OP has mentioned. Thanks anyway, I changed the answer.

Comment: Even before C++17, there's nothing to be gained from using `forward_as_tuple` here compared to `make_tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would work in `C++17`:

```
m.try_emplace({1,2,3},4,5,6);
```