# Can't Define an initializer_list in cbegin

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator, initializer-list, explicit

So I can do this:

```
for(const auto i : { 13, 42 }) cout << i << ' ';
```

But I can't do this:

```
copy_n(cbegin({ 13, 42 }), 2, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

It gives me the error:

> error: no matching function for call to `cbegin(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)`

What is it about the `for`-statement that allows this but not the `cbegin` function?

**Edit:**

It appears that the problem is that my `initializer_list` isn't being treated as an `initializer_list`, because if I do this it works:

```
copy_n(cbegin(initializer_list<int>{ 13, 42 }), 2, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/6jPg7d)

Comment: Isn't the range based `for` equivalent in usage to `std::begin()` instead of `std::cbegin()`?

Comment: @UnholySheep I thought that was contingent on whether the iterating variable was `const`?

Comment: I can't find any mention of that either on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) or the latest draft of the C++ standard (on the [github page](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/8ac95b9650ff8a796237fc4de1fdc537475074fa/source/statements.tex#L608)) - both only mention `begin` and `end`, nothing about `cbegin` or `cend`.

Comment: @UnholySheep As I mention here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395787/cant-define-an-initializer-list-in-cbegin?noredirect=1#comment87809805_50396019 whether `cbegin` or `begin` is called isn't really the point. They are effectively the same here. Using `begin` instead of `cbegin` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It seems to do so on IDEOne: https://ideone.com/NczXM6 (I also tested it on MSVC2017). Mind you that I'm not sure *why* it does though, but I think that NathanOliver's answer gives the explanation?

Comment: @NathanOliver This is UnholySheep's code on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72715aa5b2a37220

Comment: @JonathanMee OK.  I deleted my answer as Yuki is right.  there is now `cbegin` member for `std::initializer_list`

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there? I don't see one? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list furthermore I just thought `cbegin` called `begin` on a const container?!?

Comment: @JonathanMee Sorry, typo, *now* should have been *no*

Comment: I have a theory (but not enough knowledge of templates to validate it): Considering that `std::begin` is specialized for `initializer_list` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2) could it be that template type deduction fails (as in the deleted answer) and therefore `std::cbegin` does not work "normally"? And because there exists no specialization of `std::cbegin` for `initializer_list` (for some reason) the code fails to compile?

Comment: @UnholySheep Hmmm... I don't think so. I think my brackets aren't correctly being treated as an `initializer_list`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8506ac8fe6ca6f36

Comment: @NathanOliver It looks like the problem is not that anything isn't implemented for an `initializer_list` but rather my brackets aren't interpreted as an `initializer_list`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8506ac8fe6ca6f36

Comment: @JonathanMee Very weird.  I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is this using `begin`'s array constructor?!? I bet that's what it is, but I can't figure out how to validate...

Comment: I tried making simple recreations of `cbegin` and when leaving out the specialization for `std::initializer_list` the template deduction fails (see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7422641df3b274a7), but providing a specialization makes the code work as intended

Comment: @JonathanMee I wouldn't think so.  That said [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/980ac8eaf5eec060) doesn't work but if you change it to `std::begin` instead of `begin` in `main` it does.

Comment: @JonathanMee `std::initializer_list` overload `std::begin`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2  That is why it works with `begin`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmmm... Again... I don't feel like that's true. Cause if I explicitly construct an `initializer_list` `cbegin` works :/

Comment: @JonathanMee It works because now `cbegin` knows what the type is and `cbegin` forwards to `begin` and `begin` exists for `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c62c314bab90ec9a) example.  If you comment out `begin(std::initializer_list<T> il)` it will fail to compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver So `cbegin` is implemented as: `template<class C> 
constexpr auto cbegin(const C& c) -> decltype(std::begin(c))` shouldn't that pick up the `begin(initializer_list)` in the `decltype`?

Comment: Sure but it still can't determine what `C` is as `{13, 42}` doesn't have a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ 13, 42 }` is braced initializer list.  It doesn't have a type, it is just a list and it depends on how it used as how it gets treated.  `std::cbegin` is defined like

```
template< class C > 
constexpr auto cbegin( const C& c ) -> decltype(std::begin(c));
```

and since the braced initializer list doesn't have a type, the template type deduction fails.  In the ranged based for loop we use the list different.  A range based for loop expands to

```
{
    init-statement
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

with `auto && __range = range_expression ;` becoming `auto && __range = { 13, 42 }`.  Now `auto` follows template type deduction except that since the committee decide that [`auto` should work with braced initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612262/why-does-auto-x3-deduce-an-initializer-list), `auto` will deduce `{ 13, 42 }` to a `std::initiaizer_list<int>` since the list contains only `int`s.

---

If you change the code to

```
copy_n(begin({ 13, 42 }), 2, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

even though `std::begin` is defined like `cbegin` and takes a template type, `<initializer_list>` [introduces an overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2) that takes a `std::initializer_list` and that will get called instead.

Comment: I think it is true that brace-enclosed list is not necessarily an initializer-list, it depends on the context, but I think in this case it is nothing else, but an initializer-list-type object.

Comment: I was ready to accept this but then I noticed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395787/cant-define-an-initializer-list-in-cbegin?noredirect=1#comment87810453_50395787 Does this make sense?

Comment: @JonathanMee IDEone is blocked for me. Could you share the code posted there with coliru?

Comment: If you could edit your `cbegin` definition to `... -> decltype(std::begin(c))` I'd like to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Initializer list stores only pointers to the original list and by design it does not allow the user to modify the data, i.e.

```
const T* begin(); // returns a constant object
```

So the `begin` member or a `begin` free-function would be equivalent to `cbegin`. That is why only `begin` exists.

**Update**

Concerning `cbegin(std::initializer_list<int>...`: that works because you explicitly specified the type and `cbegin(const Container&...` is actually a template function, and `begin(std::initializer_list<U>...` is a different template function, as I said in the first part of the answer there is no `cbegin(std::initializer_list<U>...` function.

And the solving part is that you cannot do "chained" template deduction, it does not make sense: `Container -> std::initializer_list<U> -> std::initializer_list<int>`. Only one of the two deduction might exist, either `Container -> std::initializer_list<int>`, or  `std::initializer_list<U> -> std::initializer_list<int>`

Comment: This is simply irrelevent. `cbegin` calls the `begin` method on a const container: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin This has absolutely no bearing on the problem. Please remove this misleading answer.

Comment: Curses! Am I wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395787/cant-define-an-initializer-list-in-cbegin?noredirect=1#comment87810453_50395787

Comment: You seem to be *exactly* right... but this is not in keeping with what how I'm reading the standard to say that `cbegin` should be implemented!

Comment: I've updated my question, this *is* related to the problem, but this is not *the* problem. An actual `intializer_list` has no trouble with `cbegin`.