# auto in c++ with initializer_list

Tags: c++, auto, effective-c++

the question about effective modern c++ item 2:

```
auto x3={27};// x3's type is std::initializer_list
auto x4{27}; // x4's type is std::initializer_list
```

but when I test x4's type , I found the type of x4 is int

I don't know what type of x4

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto x4{ 27 };
    cout << typeid(x4).name();
}
```

[image]

thanks for every one, I have known the answer.

Comment: what is the question, and prefer using text instead of images.

Comment: Note that this changed in C++17.

Comment: Since C++17 `x4` is deduced as `int`. See [Why does auto x{3} deduce an initializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612534/3309790)

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely

Comment: This is a hellhole of a corner of C++, it's always nice to know the answer, but don't get too worried about it.