# What is the difference between std::initializer_list<int>({1,2,3}) and {1,2,3}?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have following template function:

```
template<typename T> void foo2(T t) {}
```

I know that I cannot call it using:

```
foo2({1,2,3});
```

because initializer list is a non deduced context for a template argument. I have to use:

```
foo2<std::initializer_list<int>>({1,2,3});
```

but I can also use:

```
foo2(std::initializer_list<int>({1,2,3}));
```

which makes me wonder what is the difference between: `{1,2,3}` and `std::initializer_list<int>({1,2,3})`?

Comment: `std::initializer_list<int>({1,2,3})` is an expression of type `std::initializer_list<int>`.  `{1,2,3}` is not an expression. Braced list can only occur in contexts that the language definition explicitly allows it,  not just anywhere that an expression can occur.

Comment: @M.M When you know an answer to a question with 0 answers, but then, it turns out it's answered in the comments. ﴾ ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°﴿

Comment: @luk32 feel free to write an answer ... i think a full answer should cover the details of the template which I'm not so sure about

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582667/why-do-auto-and-template-type-deduction-differ-for-braced-initializers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [*braced-init list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) isn't an expression, and thus doesn't have a type. When you call

```
foo2({1,2,3});
```

the compiler doesn't know what type `{1,2,3}` represents in your mind, and so it doesn't compile.

```
foo2<std::initializer_list<int>>({1,2,3});
```

compiles because here the compiler doesn't have to deduce the type, you have specified it, it is `std::initializer_list<int>`. So it can initialize `t` with `{1,2,3}`.

The third call also compiles because the compiler can deduce the type. `std::initializer_list<int>({1,2,3})` is obviously a `std::initializer_list<int>`, and so it can initialize `t` with the passed prvalue.

Comment: Note that in C++17 the "guaranteed elision" rules make your last paragraph different.  In a sense, there is no longer a value created there then elided to the function argument; it just becomes a way to initialize the function argument.  Or so I gather, I've yet to master the new rules.  (In practice, there is next to no difference in this case)