# Unable to deduce type in class with constructor taking std::array

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to create a templated class containing enum-string pairs and unable to make type deduction work. With a following code i have two problems:

```
namespace {
template<typename T, size_t S>
using EnumStringArray = std::array<std::pair<T, const char*>, S>;
}

template<typename T, size_t S>
class EnumToString {
public:
    constexpr EnumToString(const EnumStringArray<T, S>& array) :
            _array(array)
    {}
private:
    EnumStringArray<T, S> _array;
};

template<typename T, size_t S>
EnumToString(const EnumStringArray<T, S>&) -> EnumToString<T, S>;

enum MyEnum {
    One, 
    Two
};

constexpr EnumToString enumStrings = {{{    //<---- does not compile without explicit types
        {One, "One"},
        {Two, "Two"}
}}};
```

1. Why compiler can't deduce parameters of EnumToString by himself within constructor?
2. Why user deduction guide does not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{..}` has not type and cannot be deduced (except as `std::initializer_list<T>` or `T(&)[N]`).

so regular constructor, or deduction guide doesn't help with CTAD here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, as has mentioned by @Jarod42, is that in C++ brace initializers do not have any types and cannot be deduced by the compiler in the context of templates. The reason of this has been summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582667/why-do-auto-and-template-type-deduction-differ-for-braced-initializers).

To fix it, you can use an `auto` variable to deduce the type and then pass it to your template method.

```
auto x = {{One, "One"}, {Two, "Two"}};
// Now x has a type, you can pass it to a template function.
```